# Android development: main.xml does not display background when running on emulator

Tags: android

My background of main.xml looks ok on eclipse, but when it is running, the background won't display. I already set up 'setContentView(R.layout.main);' There are one TextView and two Buttons in main.xml. Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/lovescore"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0" 
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" for every all buttons and textview then see if it is working.

Comment: clean and build the project . a known bug

Comment: share you activity also.